# How do fluids behave in a vacuum?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

My textbook says that the volume of liquids is assumed to be such under atmospheric pressure. What if the atmospheric pressure is reduced? Will the liquid stop exerting pressure according to Pascal's law? Will there be an intrinsic force that the liquid will exert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pull a vacuum on a liquid, when the ambient pressure exerted on the liquid falls to the vapor pressure of the liquid at that temperature, the liquid starts to boil. Pulling such a vacuum very suddenly on a sample of water will cause the water to explode violently into vapor by boiling all at once.